# SQL to calulate distance travelled

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a SQL problem I am trying to crack so that I can make a report that shows how much distance travelled in Kilometers in a date range that the user selects.

I have two tables that contain the information I need to use, I have linked the two tables together and currently, the report shows what is currently is displayed on the odometers.

Using this code:

```
Select FLEET_ID, ALLOCATED_STATE, DRIVER, ODO_READING, B.Date_Added
From TABLE1 as A
left outer JOIN DATEBASE_NAME..TABLE2 as B
on A.Unique_ID = B.FLEET_UNIQUE_ID
WHERE B.Unique_ID is not NULL
AND B.Date_Added between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Every month the Odometer is updated in the table what I want to happen is once the date range is selected by the user it subtracts the previous Odometer from the selected result which will display the distance traveled between the two entries.

Thanks Guys!
Jack

[Results of March](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzXjE.png)

[Results of Apirl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbTvC.png)

Comment: What do you mean by `it subtracts the previous Odometer from the selected result`? Post sample data and the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `lag()`.  Your question is a bit short on information, but something like this:

```
select *, odo_reading - prev_odo_reading
from (Select FLEET_ID, ALLOCATED_STATE, DRIVER, ODO_READING, B.Date_Added,
             lag(odo_reading) over (partition by feel_ti, driver order by b.date_added) as prev_odo_reading
      From TABLE1 A left outer JOIN
           DATEBASE_NAME..TABLE2 B
           on A.Unique_ID = B.FLEET_UNIQUE_ID
      where B.Unique_ID is not NULL
     ) x
where B.Date_Added between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Comment: Sadly it did not work. I get an error: An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: @JackSchier . . . This is a **SELECT** statement, so it cannot generate that error.  I think this answers the question you actually asked here.  If you have a different question, you should ask a *new* question.

Comment: `An item with the same key has already been added.`. I'm guessing you see this when you use the query above in an SSRS dataset. That's because you have the same column name used more than once in the output. Check your results SSMS or similar and look for the duplicates then fix. IMO this answer should be accepted.